# How to remove the white-space created by an image?

Tags: html, css

[image: Image describing my issue]

I want the red square on the top/left of the textbox/textarea but I don't want the white-space created. The attached image, top is what it looks like without the image, the middle is what I have now (with the white-space circled in purple) and the bottom is what I'd like it to look like.

The current image tag looks like this:

```
<img src="images/red.png" style="position:relative;display:block;top:10px;z-index:1;" />
```

More code, last line is where the cell with the image and textarea are:

```html
<table style="Width:100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
    <th colspan="5" align="Left">
      <B>Numeric Tests</B>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
    <th align="Left" style="Width:250px;">
      <B>Metric</B>
    </th>
    <th align="CENTER" style="Width:75px;">
      <B>Target</B>
    </th>
    <th align="CENTER" style="Width:75px;">
      <B>ACT</B>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" align="Left">
      <B>Comments</B>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="Left" style="Width:250px;"><b>test value 1:</b></td>
    <td align="Left" style="Width:75px;"><b>74.1</b></td>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="PaleVioletRed" style="Width:75px;" title="The Actual Value must be >= the Target to be satisfied.">65.97</th>
    <td bgcolor="White"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10x10" style="position:relative;display:block;top:10px;z-index:1;" /><textarea name="comments7000" rows="2" cols="20" id="comments7000" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:100%;font-size:Large;">
    fasdfasdf</textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: isn't it the `top:10px` ? also try to provide more code to debugg

Comment: in your element's style, `top: 10px` will set the image 10 pixels from the top -- try changing that to `top: 0px`

Comment: @Doug I want the image where it is. I just don't want the white-space (circled in purple), changing it to 0px put's it where the white space is.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa what code do you need? It's an image and a textarea in a cell of a table.

Comment: the parent can influence it's children. and vice versa, so please provide more code

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa added.

Comment: What's the chance that you will create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) snippet in your question so we could actually see the problem and try to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrap the textarea and the img inside a div, and then as others mentioned position relative and absolute should do it, if you have any questions on how this does work, feel free to ask.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td>div {
  position: relative;
  /*to remove the white space below remove this so see it*/
  font-size: 0;
}

td>div>img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

td>div>textarea {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: Large;
}
```

```html
<table style="Width:100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
    <th colspan="5" align="Left">
      <B>Numeric Tests</B>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="LightBlue">
    <th align="Left" style="Width:250px;">
      <B>Metric</B>
    </th>
    <th align="CENTER" style="Width:75px;">
      <B>Target</B>
    </th>
    <th align="CENTER" style="Width:75px;">
      <B>ACT</B>
    </th>
    <th colspan="2" align="Left">
      <B>Comments</B>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="Left" style="Width:250px;">
      <b>test value 1:</b>
    </td>
    <td align="Left" style="Width:75px;">
      <b>74.1</b>
    </td>
    <th align="Left" bgcolor="PaleVioletRed" style="Width:75px;" title="The Actual Value must be >= the Target to be satisfied.">65.97</th>
    <td bgcolor="White">
      <div>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10x10 " /><textarea name="comments7000" rows="2" cols="20" id="comments7000">fasdfasdf</textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative` for your image and set `position: relative` to its parent.

In this way you will not have the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to `<td>` of this table cell and change position property of your image to `position:absolute`. It will work.